# Como usar MySQL em Android

Tags: android, mysql

Após algumas pesquisas, vi que o único banco de dados que o Android pode utilizar é SQLite, está correta essa informação?

Pois eu tenho uma aplicação que se conecta a um banco de dados online (MySQL) e gostaria de criar um aplicativo em Android que usasse a mesma base de dados, é possível?

Se sim, como posso me conectar a uma base `mysql`?

Comment: SQLite é o que o Android usa no aparelho. Fora do aparelho você usa o que quiser.

Comment: Quem e porque está votando para fechar essa pergunta? Ela se encaixa perfeitamente no escopo do site.

Comment: Esta pergunta está sendo discutida no meta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/971/comparando-a-experi%C3%AAncia-do-so-com-o-sopt

Comment: Tome muito cuidado com acesso externo a bancos de dados diretamente dos apps Android. Isso deixa uma falha muito grande de segurança entre seu app e seu banco de dados. Qualquer tipo de acesso a "banco de dados externo" (vamos chamar assim), deve ser feito via WebServices. Da uma olhada nesse artigo http://www.androidpro.com.br/usando-banco-de-dados-externo-no-android/.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Como é respondido [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13002532/1606920), é possível utilizar um banco de dados online, no seu caso o MySQL, desde que você possua um:

- Webservice
- Cliente

**Webservice** 
Você deverá fazer a requisição no banco e retornar uma resposta para ser processada, geralmente um [JSON](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), que pode ser enviada, por exemplo, com [php](/questions/tagged/php), da seguinte forma:

```php
<?php
   echo json_encode($minha_info);
?>
```

Isso retornará um `JSON` para o cliente.

**Cliente**
É possível usar o pacote [JSON do próprio Java](http://json.org/java/), como neste [exemplo](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidJSON/article.html) e recuperar as informações no cliente. O exemplo a seguir utilizará a leitura de um feed do twitter:

```java
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  String readTwitterFeed = readTwitterFeed();
  try {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(readTwitterFeed);
    Log.i(ParseJSON.class.getName(), "Number of entries " + jsonArray.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
      JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
      Log.i(ParseJSON.class.getName(), jsonObject.getString("text"));
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}

public String readTwitterFeed() {
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
  HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
  HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/vogella.json"); //Aqui ele pega o json do tutorial, nessa linha que o seu cliente vai declarar o webservice que enviará o json
  try {
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
    int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
    if (statusCode == 200) {
      HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
      InputStream content = entity.getContent();
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
      String line;
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        builder.append(line);
      }
    } else {
      Log.e(ParseJSON.class.toString(), "Failed to download file");
    }
  } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: Faltou citar que o aplicativo Android pode fazer uma conexão direta com o banco MySQL usando JDBC. Só não uma abordagem recomendada.

Comment: Na realidade ele [não é recomendado por não funcionar, por causa das limitações técnicas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221620/android-jdbc-not-working-classnotfoundexception-on-driver/7221716#7221716), por isso preferi não citar.

Answer (score 4):

Felipe, na verdade funciona sim! Eu mesmo estou desenvolvendo um sistema para bares e restaurantes com um app e estou utilizando conexão direta do MySQL com o Android, e, ao contrário do que a maioria diz, não fica lento.

A única ressalva é q a API do android não permite que vc faça troca de dados pela rede (seja pelo Wi-Fi ou pelo 3G/4G) utilizando a thread principal (UIThread). Para isso existem as classes auxiliares como a *AsyncTask*, presente na **API**, que auxilia na execução de processos em segundo plano. Todo processo de comunicação entre o app e o banco deverá ser feito através de uma thread secundária, ou seja, um processo em segundo plano (inclusive a própria conexão).

Acabei esquecendo de postar um exemplo de como implementar a conexão do android com o MySQL.

Procurando na net achei esse tutorial bem interessante e bem parecido com a forma que eu utilizo a conexão.

[Conexão android com MySQL utilizando a classe AsyncTask](http://inovarecriar.com/home/android-conectando-ao-mysql-com-asynctask/)

Espero ter ajudado!  Abraços

Comment: Oi João, bem-vindo ao site. Isso que você postou ficou no meio do caminho entre um comentário à resposta do Felipe e uma resposta mesmo à pergunta. Se quiser [edit] e torná-la uma resposta mais completa (inclusive com códigos de exemplo no corpo da resposta), seria uma boa. Se preferir, posso converter em comentário pra você, é só me avisar (você precisaria de 50 pontos no site para poder comentar na resposta do felipe). Obrigado.

Comment: João blz, concordo com você mas depende muito do desenvolvedor e vários cuidados a ser tomados principalmente relacionados a transações, eu tive um problema semelhante e resolvi utilizar a conexão direta ficou bem mais rápido por se tratar de queries simples e acesso somente via rede local(wifi) e por não ter que passar por nenhum serviço.

Answer (score 0):

Você terá que construir uma API (Geralmente usa-se **json/rest**) para que possa se comunicar com o servidor, e ele tratar os dados pra vc.