# Mysql com android

Tags: android, mysql

Procurei em varios foruns sobre como integrar mysql com android, coisa bem simples, tipo listar os dados de uma tabela salva em um servidor mysql externo.

Usando java normal consegui fazer usando jdbc. Tentei usar o mesmo com android mas tive problemas com o jar na hora de importar para o projeto. Procurei outras alternativas e vi sobre JSON. Porem como nao tenho conhecimentos de PHP, o metodo ensinava usando PHP

Minha duvida é: Existe algum jeito de ler dados de uma tabela mysql so usando java no android, sem php? Seria possivel com sqlite ou isso é só para bancos  internos no sistema??

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como usar MySQL em Android](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7763/como-usar-mysql-em-android)

Answer (score 3):

O SQLite é o banco interno da sua aplicação Android. Para acessar um MySQL em um servidor externo você pode usar JDBC mas não é recomendado fazer assim por diversos motivos. O certo é chamar Web Services presentes no servidor (que não precisam ser em PHP, podem ser em Java) que retornam os dados do banco em formato JSON.