# Conexão SQL Server

Tags: java, android, sql, sql-server

Estou tentando fazer conexão direta com o SQL Server, para testes, mas na hora do teste de "Cadastrar" clicando no botão, o app simplesmente trava, há algo de errado no código?

```
package br.com.agemstar.testesql;

import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText edtnome, edtend;
Button carregar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  edtnome = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtNome);
    edtend = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtEnd);
    carregar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnN1);

    carregar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            cadastrarUsuario();
        }
    });
}

public Connection conexaoBD(){
    Connection connection = null;
    try{
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.0.169;databaseName=ANDROID_SQL;user=sa;password=@dm1n102030;");
    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return connection;
}

public void cadastrarUsuario(){
    try{
        PreparedStatement pst = conexaoBD().prepareStatement("insert into usuarios values (?,?)");
        pst.setString(1,edtnome.getText().toString());
        pst.setString(2,edtend.getText().toString());
        pst.executeUpdate();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"REGISTRO CONCLUIDO",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A tabela 'usuarios' tem apenas nome e endereço?  Caso haja outros valores, é necessário declarar em quais campos você vai inserir: INSERT INTO USUARIOS (TXT_NOME, TXT_ENDERECO) VALUES (?, ?)

Comment: Trava, mas mostra mensagem de erro, qual?

Comment: Provavelmente que o android não permite conexão direta com Servidores de Banco de dados. Como pode ver [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/7778/38938). agora se quiser realmente conectar direto com o banco [Tem essa outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/44189/38938)

Comment: @João, o aplicativo apenas para de responder e tenho que fecha-lo.

Comment: @Csorgo, irei fazer este teste, e aviso-o depois.